# Is React Hooks + Context API ready for making websites for clients?

Tags: reactjs, performance, axios, react-hooks, react-context

So I have been using Class and Function Components to make websites for clients, but recently I discovered Hooks and Context API which makes the code way less messy and easy to write and understand. And my doubt is if Hooks and Context API are here to stay if they are supported and secure enough to make websites for clients.

Comment: We have an app in production that uses Hooks and Context. We do use context to keep our data between different routes. However, this is not a unique scenario with Hooks or context; The same thing can be achieved with Class-based components and/or Redux.

Comment: They are definitely ready for production. They are out of the beta phase and have been for awhile now. Plenty of apps (including my own) are deployed to production using them.

Comment: @Nomz So the best way to choose is according to the magnitude of an app?

Comment: @SpecialCharacter Thanks, I feel more confident now to use them.